# Combining two md5 hash in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, md5

How can I combine two MD5 hash values of a file together and output to one MD5 value?

I'm using `md5-file` npm package to get md5 hash of a file.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is why/how do you get 2 values for one file?

Comment: Oh. What I mean is combining two md5 hash together, and get only one as an output. Like md5_1 + md5_2 + ... ==> only one md5 value.

Comment: Im not sure what you want, but your approch seems ok to me, concat the the two md5 checksum into one string, and create out of that concatenated string a new md5 checksum